# How to know in a Makefile if `make` is invoked from ViM?

Tags: vim, makefile

In short, I need to know in a Makefile whether `make is being invoked from ViM or not. Is there a certain variable (such as ENVIRONMENT or something), that ViM would set to a specific value?.

The reason I need this is the following:

If called from bash, I could do all sorts of wonderful stuff for user (or myself), such as giving messages as to which subsystem is being built and highlighting errors and warnings.

The problem is however that, when called from ViM, the error messages already get captured and introducing `\x1b` commands (for color) makes the messages incomprehensible to ViM. What I want to do is basically disable coloring when `:make` is issued in ViM.

Even though I'd rather have the Makefile resolve it, I am open to other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside Vim, you can set environment variables that are inherited by opened shells; e.g.

```
:let $INSIDE_VIM = 1
```

If this is just about `:make`, you can manipulate the `'makeprg'` that determines what is invoked:

```
:set makeprg=export\ INSIDE_VIM=1;make
```

If you're just concerned about the escape sequences for coloring, you could just set `$TERM` to something that doesn't understand colors (`dumb` maybe?) and if the coloring isn't hard-coded (which unfortunately is a big if in many tools), it should obey the terminal setting and not print the escape sequences.

Comment: I have a config that says whether it should use builds or not. The check in the Makefile thus simply overrides the config. I hadn't thought about checking whether the terminal can show colors or not, though (thanks for pointing that out). Nevertheless, probably changing `TERM` itself is not so good since other programs (bash itself for example) may rely on it.

Comment: The `let $INSIDE_VIM = 1` is great though!

Comment: As long as you don't switch `xterm` to `dtterm`, but "downgrade" the terminal capabilities, it should be fine. But I'm no expert on terminals, and it probably won't work all the time; just added that for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

I'd either tell the makefile explicitly that you don't want colouring, or filter it out.
If you try to guess inside the makefile, it's liable to break when you use a different editor, or shell, or tweak your environment.

My preference would be to just filter out the non-printable characters:

```
:set makeprg=make\ $*\ \\\|filter
```

since this doesn't require explicit workarounds in the makefile. However, the required filter itself is non-trivial: see for example [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684) on unix.stackexchange.

Alternatively, as already suggested, the easiest way to tell your makefile explicitly is to add a variable to your invocation:

```
:set makeprg=make\ NO_COLOUR=1
```

or whatever (`make` should be the current value of `makeprg`).

.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter your vim binding to `SOURCE="vim" make`, so in your makefile the `$$SOURCE` variable is set to "vim".

Edit: I see you are in fact not using bindings in vim, you can use them with the following line in your `.vimrc` (or `/etc/vimrc`) like this:

```
:nmap <F5> <CR>SOURCE="vim" :make<CR>
```

This will bind F5 to what you want

Comment: Why the double `$`? Also, could I alias `:make` to `SOURCE="vim" make` instead?

Comment: it is what I needed in my Makefile to print the content of the SOURCE variable `all:echo "$$SOURCE"` which printed vim with my invocation

Answer (score 1):

You could check `MYVIMRC`or `VIMRUNTIME` environment variables.  On my GNU/Linux distribution, `SHLVL` value is 1 from bash and 2 when make is invoked from within `vim`.

Comment: These are nice and easy. However, `MYVIMRC` may not be defined if `.vimrc` doesn't exist. `VIMRUNTIME` may anyway be defined by a user (although unlikely). `SHLVL` is not so robust, as `vim` may not have been run from a level 1 bash. I'll wait for other answers, but `VIMRUNTIME` so far seems to be the most reliable solution.